# How to combine a readProcess monad with where in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

Below script is intended as an extension of a published and working [Pandoc Haskell filter script](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html#latex-for-wordpress). What has been added is a call to the shell command `curl`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
-- svgtex.hs
import Text.Pandoc.JSON
import System.Process

curl latex = readProcess "curl" ["-d", "type=tex&q=" ++ latex, "http://localhost:16000"] ""

main = toJSONFilter svgtex
  where svgtex (Math style latex) = do
            svg <- curl latex
            return (Math style (svg))
        svgtex x = x
```

However, being completely new to Haskell functional programming, it is not surprising that my script fails with:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO Inline' with actual type `Inline'
In the expression: x
In an equation for `svgtex': svgtex x = x
In an equation for `main':
...
```

Despite having skipped over a number on-line Haskell tutorials and StackExchange Q&As, the concept of monads has still not entirely dawned upon me. Hence, a detailed explanation about all things wrong in above script would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Try `svgtex x = return x`.

Comment: @chi That did it! Thank you very much. Feel free to post it as an answer to give you more reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
    svgtex x = x
```

The complier complains that

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO Inline' with actual type `Inline'
```

because `x` is an `Inline`, while `svgtex` must return an `IO Inline`. To inject the `x` into the `IO` monad, we can simply use the `return` function

```
    svgtex x = return x
```

To fully understand what's going on see any monad tutorial (or LYAH). Roughly put, a value of type `IO Inline` represents an action that can perform any amount of I/O and finally return a value of type `Inline`. The `return` function is used to turn a pure value into a dummy `IO` action which does not do any I/O, but simply return the result.